# How to retrieve data from a database and render it accordingly with exrpessjs

Tags: node.js, express

I have created a simple admin panel simulation environment.

What I want to do are just simple CRUD-operations through the admin panel, so from the admin panel, I can add data, which goes to the database and updates my client-panel.

This is my system: I have a controller.js which is passed to my serverjs and into my routes/index.js where I assign the values that I need

**controller.js**

```
/* ~Require Modules~*/
var mysql = require('mysql'); // MySQL
var dbconfig = require('./config/database'); // Load database-configuration

/* ~MySQL Properties~ */
//Create connection with MYSQL
var connection = mysql.createConnection(dbconfig.connection); // Establish connection with database

module.exports = function () {
        var Query = {
            read: 'SELECT * FROM page'          
    }
};
```

I want all my querys to be organized and reside inside of this controllersjs file.

**The problem is** is that I can't figure out how *I could retrieve data from that Query* that I have already written

a simpler example would be this:

```
module.exports.msg = "hello"
```

and now I can simply go to my `index.js` and call out `controller.msg` and It will retrieve `hello`

But If I want to do multiple different operations then this wouldn't be the best viable solution.

Comment: A really great first step is to read the mysql package doc. https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#introduction

Comment: This doesn't really get me any further.
Yeah sure i can write the whole function out but How can I exactly retrieve that data?

Answer (score 0):

```
connection.query('SELECT * FROM page', function (error, results, fields) {
    if (error) throw error;
    results.forEach((result) => {
        // do something
        console.log(result);  
    })
});
```

You can write  a  generic  function that would return the result and then you  can use the returned data in the calling function.